# How can I add a placeholder and multiline text input to my form fields? React Native

Tags: react-native

How can I add a placeholder and multiline text input to my form fields? React Native?

I want to add a placeholder in my subject line and I want to have my message field multiline 
I have tried to add placeholders and multilines but I dont think I am using it correctly. please help me out

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

import t from 'tcomb-form-native';

const Form = t.form.Form;

const User = t.struct({
name: t.String,
email: t.String,
subject: t.String,
message: t.String
});

const formStyles = {
  ...Form.stylesheet,
 formGroup: {
 normal: {
  marginBottom: 10
},
},
controlLabel: {
normal: {
  color: 'blue',
  fontSize: 18,
  marginBottom: 7,
  fontWeight: '600'
},
// the style applied when a validation error occours
error: {
  color: 'red',
  fontSize: 18,
  marginBottom: 7,
  fontWeight: '600'
 }
 }
}

const options = {
fields: {
name: {
  error: 'Please enter your name',

},
email: {
  error: 'Please enter your email adress'
},
message: {
  error: 'Please enter message'
 },
},
stylesheet: formStyles,
};

export default class App extends Component {
handleSubmit = () => {
const value = this._form.getValue();
console.log('value: ', value);
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

    <Form 
      ref={c => this._form = c}
      type={User} 
      options={options}
    />
    <Button
      title="Send Message"
      onPress={this.handleSubmit}
    />
   </View>
  );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
justifyContent: 'center',
marginTop: 50,
padding: 20,
backgroundColor: '#ffffff',

 },
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/SJiexSeiW

Link to my code so far to view in snack expo

Comment: Hi Emily, it would be useful if you included a minimal code example in the question. External links often start breaking, rendering the question unusable in the future.

Comment: okay I will post my code instead

Comment: I figured out the place holder, just need to get multiline working for message field

Comment: Okay I think I got both working, however the textbox remains the same size instead of expanding with the multilines